# Fragments are drawn on top of eachother

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

The scenario is this...I click on a button that loads the next fragment. While the animation is still going I hit the recent apps button. After the recent apps screen is shown i return to my app.

Then I see the two fragments drawn on top of each other. As if Android forgot to remove the previous fragment.
I click back to remove all fragments until I reach the first fragment loaded in this FragmentActivity. I log all the fragments I get from FragmentManager and it only shows one. But I still see two fragments drawn one on top of the other. The one that should have been removed is not responding to touch events and the other one responds as it should.

Is this an Android bug or my fault? Is there any way to fix this or prevent it from happening ?

It does not happen every time. This is how I load my fragments

```
public void loadNewFragment(AnimFragment newFragment, boolean addToSTack, boolean animate, String tag) {

    if (newFragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter_from_right, R.anim.fragment_exit_to_left, R.anim.fragment_enter_from_left, R.anim.fragment_exit_to_right);

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, tag);

        if (addToSTack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        }

        int transactionId = transaction.commit();
        newFragment.setTransactionId(transactionId);
    }

}
```

and I remove them on back pressed with

`getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`

Comment: Where are you calling `loadNewFragment()` in your code?

Comment: on the click event of a button

Comment: Then please post that bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion "below" fragment is `onPause()` state and it's still alive and visible.

Try to use white background on the root layout of the front fragment to avoid showing the below fragment. Moreover the root layout size (width and height) of the front fragment should be match_parent.

Check this site to understand `Fragment` lifecycle.

https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-1-fragments/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications.html